# #Type! Error in MsAccess text box

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a dashboard in MsAccess with a few textboxes using dCounts and few of the text boxes summing those dcounts. Some of the ones summing are throwing #type! errors. But only sometimes. If I refresh the page, some disappear while others appear. Sometimes all work. The textboxes summing all have something like this:
=[txt1an]+[txt1bn]+[txt1cn]+[txt2a1n]+[txt2a2n]+[txt2a3n]

Comment: check for nulls.  Use NZ or use criteria in your DCOUNT to exclude null values.

Comment: now I get a #size! error.

Comment: I believe it might be the fact that the sums are run before the dcounts, so it throws an error since the dcounts are yet to return the data. any chance to make the dcounts go first?

Comment: I cannot replicate issue. I can sum textboxes running DCount just fine. Need to review db - if you want to provide I recommend Box.com fileshare site.

Comment: It has to do with speed. If the sum is made before the dcount, it throws the error. Since I dont know how to make Access go through the Dcounts first, I removed the header where the sums were, and then re added it. this way Access only does them last. This isnt really a solution, but it is working for me.